# PHP with MSSQL Connection not working in command Line (cmd)

Tags: php, sql-server, cmd

I want to run my php Script from the command line but it always throws an error.
If i run the same Script in a Browser everything works fine. There seems to be a problem with the paths. But the .dll files are in the correct folder. I also tried "Run as Administrator" but the error still exists.

**Browser**

[image]

**Console**

[image]

Comment: we can't see your folder structure or your code, so it's hard to be really sure what is wrong. But possibly it relates to relative paths. Try executing the code from the same folder where it runs when in the browser (i.e. the "sites" folder) and see if that helps. Maybe you'll need to use some absolute paths for the included files (although that then reduces its portability to other environments, which is annoying)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that PHP CLI uses different phpini config. you need to set a custom config and load it with new settings:
use [this article](https://inchoo.net/dev-talk/custom-php-ini-php-cli/) to create a custom .ini and use it with CLI

Answer (score 0):

You need to use static paths for your includes like

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php
```